# Team Foundation Server Design

Tags: reporting-services, tfs

Right now, I have Team Foundation Server 2010 running on our SSRS server. Is best practice to have TFS on it's own server?

Also, I have a Team Foundation Server project called Reports which contain sub folders of each of our department's reports; Purchasing, Accounting, Sales, etc... I did that so that I didn't have to change the deployment settings. Is there a best practice for this or am I over thinking it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by changing the deployment settings?

But there are no issues with installing TFS on the same server as SSRS.  It should just work.  The only problems you might run into is if you have a lot of TFS users overloading the single server, but MS suggests that a single-server TFS can support up to 500 users: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd578592.aspx

Comment: I have a project called 'Sales' with all sales reports. Each report "deploys" to the live SSRS. The settings for that are in the project properties. I actually have to change those settings manually on the entire project to deploy a report to test instance before deploying to the live SSRS. Should I just create another project for the test reports?